# How to print % symbol in receipt from raw text in ESC POS?

Tags: printing, thermal-printer, receipt, escpos

Please, I need help. What is the right command in ESC POS so I can print the % symbol in my receipt? I used raw text for my receipt, but when I write the % symbol, for example, Standard Tax 6%, instead of printing Tax 6%, it printed Tax 60... Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured it out. I'm using printf in Linux terminal to type the command and the text for my receipt. I just add \x25, where 25 is the hexadecimal for % symbol in Ascii Table. Simple things, but I took some time to figure it out, as I'm a beginner and not-so-good in understanding English, can I say that, hee. I hope this will help someone out there later on that might in the same situation in writing raw text and command in ESC POS.

Comment: Maybe you should use a library like escpos-php or python-escpos.